# Kubernetes: A Way to Manually Route Traffic to Different Replicas

Tags: docker, kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have a container (a machine learning application) which is capable of loading pre-trained ml-models stored in a persistent volume. I can ask the application to load a particular model by giving its name via its REST API.

Now I want to scale up this application so that, I can load whatever the model, in any of the replicas (not in all of them) and should be able to parse data from that model.

I know this can be done by having multiple deployments and multiple services pointing to each of those deployments so that each instance will have a separate node port and I can access the REST API of each instance through these different node ports. By doing this, I can keep a record of which model is loaded on which instance in my own.

Is there any recommended way to accomplish this requirement without having multiple deployments but through replicas?  (Like maintaining a single deployment file with replicas and a manual load balancer at the service level)

Comment: You're asking if you can have one deployment with multiple pods, and you want to manually load balance traffic to these pods?

Comment: Yes. Need to manually load balance the traffic as the models loaded on different instances are different.

Comment: If you had a single Service, and you sent it a request, how would it know where to send it?  You might need to build this routing layer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the preferred way to achieve this is through multiple deployments and services.

Unless created manually, replicasets are managed by the deployment and you won't be able to have a single deployment with multiple replicasets running  different versions.

It will definitely be easier for you to have one service + deployment per version and a single ingress in front to route the traffic based on some piece of information. It could be a header, sub-domain, path, etc.

To generate all your deployments and services, you could have a look at [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/).